# mysql select doesn't include data which is compared by current timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, select, timestamp

Learning to write sql queries and facing some issues.

The query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM competitions c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT competitionId, SUM(quantity) AS quantity 
    FROM tickets 
    GROUP BY competitionId
) t ON t.competitionId = c.id 
WHERE 
  c.winnerId IS NULL 
  AND t.quantity = c.maxEntries
    OR
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= c.endAt;
```

This returns only one results but should return two results.

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= c.endAt;
```

Should also include one more record but this statement is skipped for whatever reason...

The competition table records:
[image]

The record which is marked in red square do match to the where condition. Why then it wouldn't be included?

Comment: With logic including AND and OR in SQL you need to group them using PAREN:
(c.winnerId IS NULL 
  AND t.quantity = c.maxEntries)
    OR
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= c.endAt;

Comment: Your query is not filtered only by the WHERE clause, but by the ON clause of the join also.

Comment: The thing is if I would change "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= c.endAt" to "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() <= c.endAt" then it would include timestamp condition too.

But I need the opposite thing. I need to get the records which doesn't have a winner id and is either ended (Current Timestamp is higher or equal to c.endAt) or maxEntries equal to total tickets(t.quantity = c.maxEntries).

Comment: Even if I would remove those 2 previous where conditions and would leave   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= c.endAt; it would still do not work. 

I just want to understand why it is so, that comparison by timestamp works like so.

Comment: Post sample data of both tables, better in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7 to reproduce your problem.

Comment: All good @forpas. I am really thankful to you. As you pointed me in the right direction.

The problem was that - I was using wrong join. I needed "LEFT JOIN" because "INNER JOIN" wouldn't include needed rows as  after INNER JOIN the needed records wouldn't even be presents as those didn't had any tickets  thus for SUM(quantity) wouldn't be applied. Not sure if I got that wrong. But I fixed everything. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from ***INNER JOIN*** to ***LEFT JOIN*** gives desired results.
The query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM competitions c
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT competitionId, SUM(quantity) AS quantity  
  FROM tickets GROUP BY competitionId
  ) t ON t.competitionId = c.id
WHERE 
  c.winnerId IS NULL AND 
  (t.quantity=c.maxEntries OR CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= c.endAt)
```